# characteristic classes of $SO(3)$-bundles over $\mathbb{CP}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let us consider the complex line bundle $\xi$ over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ which is completely defined by its restriction on a complex projective line; this restriction is denoted by $\xi^{\prime}$ and the Euler characteristic of $\xi^{\prime}$ we denote by $e(\xi)$.

Now consider the bundle $\xi \oplus 1_{\mathbb{R}}$ over $\mathbb{CP}^2$; we are interested in the corresponding $SO(3)$-bundle that also is denoted by $\xi \oplus 1_{\mathbb{R}}$. The value of the Stiefel–Whitney class $w(\xi \oplus 1_{\mathbb{R}})$ on a projective line equals $e(\xi)\, \text{mod}\, 2$.

Assume that $e(\xi)$ is even; there is the class in $H^4(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ such that this class  is the complete obstruction to the existence of a section of $\xi \oplus 1_{\mathbb{R}}$. The value of this class on $[\mathbb{CP}^2]$ we denote by $k(\xi)$.

What is the connection between the numbers $k(\xi)$ and $e(\xi)$?

Comment: Your text is very confusing. E.g. the *top* SW class is the euler class reduced mod 2. Furthermore summing a complex and a real line bundle gives you a real 3-dimensional bundle. Obstructions for a real section would lie in $H^3(CP^2)=0$. Hence such a bundle always has a real section. But this is clear by definition, since you have a trivial summand. So $k(\xi)$ would be trivial.

Comment: I am taking about a section of the corresponding $SO(3)$-bundle.

Comment: This is related and needs to be re-opened: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846746/79069, please vote up/reopen.